# Rails 4 automatically display values when changes are made in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, dynamic, live

I have this simple Rails app that connects to a MySQL database locally.

I have separate Ruby application that runs on its own (the Rails app does not know of the Ruby app's existence) and makes changes to that same database.

Currently, the home page of the Rails app displays the contents of a single table statically.  Is there a way to display the contents dynamically? Where as the Ruby application is doing its own thing and Rails just sits there displaying everything that is currently happening within the database without refreshing or clicking any button.

Edit: My intent for the Rails app is to create a custom Web Interface for the database.  If possible, I am trying to avoid SSEs since I've read that SSEs are not compatible with IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the dynamic portion of the display as an Ajax-oriented display, and then in javascript use a timer to regularly kick off an Ajax-based update to the form information.

How to do this is highly dependent on what you're displaying and how your data is structured.  You will want to have a way to identify time-based changes to the data, in order to tell when the last update happened, so that you don't send all of the form data when nothing has changed.

A complete solution is fairly complicated, and far beyond the scope of what can be covered in a SO answer.  If you're learning, it's a good exercise for design and developing some great Rails skills.  However, if it's a pressing need for an existing system, you might want to consider finding a freelancer to help develop it.